# RESTORE WITH NORECOVERY sQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

What is the need of "NORECOVERY" option,while restoring the database in SQL SERVER?

One situation in which Server 02 is acting as mirror server in partnership with server 01 ;when mirroring a database DB1990.What is the need of mentioning the NONRECOVERY option,while restoring the fulldatabase  backup and the log backups?

- a)   Backup  DB1990 on server01 by using full backup

  b) Restore the
  full database backup of  DB1990  by using a **norecovery** option on
  server02  as  DB1990

c)  Backup  DB1990 on server01 by using
transactional log backup .Restore the transactional log backup using
the **Non recovery** option on server02

What is the need of **nonrecovery** option over here?

Answer (score 4):

In a mirroring session , the mirror database is always in a restoring state. The reason is The principal database is constantly sending logs to the mirror database and Mirror database is constantly restoring these logs on its self.

Therefore before starting a mirroring session between two servers you are required to do a full backup restore with NORECOVERY , which leaves the database in restoring state and logs can be applied.

Comment: THANKS..WHAT EXACTLY Is the NORECOVERY option.What if i do not mention Norecovoery in this case?

Comment: Like I have already mentioned, the Mirror database needs to be in restoring state in order to be able to restore the logs coming from principal Server. When we restore a database with norecovery it leaves the database in restoring state. it means logs can be restored on this database now. Otherwise if we use WITH RECOVERY option when restoring the full backup it will restore the database and will bring the database online. which we do not need if we want this database to be a mirror in a mirroring session.